# node js passport js username field error and password field error doesn't display when the form submiting

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to create a sign up page all the functionalities are working fine. But, if username field and password field submitted empty, the page redirect to the same page but it doesn't show where the error coming from. Can you please anyone help me to fix this. Why is this hapening? I'll put the code below i created.

thank you

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        if(req.body.first == "" || req.body.last == "" || req.body.email == ""){
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Fields must be required'));
        }
        if(username == ""){
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Username must be required'));
        }
        User.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, function(err, user1) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            User.findOne({'local.usernreqame': username}, function(err, user2){
                if (err) return done(err);
                if (user1) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already exist.'));
                }
                if (user2) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already exist.'));
                }
                else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.local.username = username;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.usertype = "592000f0161d63ac334358d3";
                    newUser.first = req.body.first;
                    newUser.last = req.body.last;
                    newUser.email = req.body.email;
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            })  
        });
    });
}));
```

all the routes i created for this app

```
module.exports = function(app, passport){
    app.get('/home', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });

    app.get('/sign-up', function(req, res){
        res.render('signup', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    app.post('/sign-up', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/sign-up',
        failureFlash : true
    }));

    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('users/profile', {
            user : req.user 
        });
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res){
        res.render('404');
    });
}
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Here you can see the template file also

```
<form method="post" action="/sign-up">
    <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Enter Firstname"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Enter Lastname" ><br/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail" ><br/>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>

<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div><%=message%></div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Could you provide your routes configuration?

Comment: yes let me update with the routes

Comment: In your `GET /sign-up` route, is the `req.flash('signupMessage')` returning anything?

Comment: yes it is. it works all the fields but not for the username field and password field in passport js

Comment: Are the value of `username` and `password` `empty` or `undefined`? Because, if it is `undefined`, I believe this `if(username == "")` won't work.

Comment: so do you need to see the signup ejs template. or can you provide an answer how can i fix this issue

Comment: Yes, I want to see the template. Plus, if you put a `console.log` like this: `app.get('/sign-up', function(req, res){ console.log(req.flash('signupMessage') );
        res.render('signup', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });` Does the message appers in the log?

Comment: yes i logged the console and it doesn't appear on the console wait now i'll edit this tack

Comment: Passport strategies are meant to authenticate already-registered users, they are not meant to register new users. The strategy function will never get called if `username` or `password` are empty, in which case Passport will immediately redirect to `failureRedirect`. There is a module called [`passport-local-register`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-register) that may be useful.

Comment: can you please provide it with an answer

Comment: What template is that? `signup`? Where are you trying to put the `message`?

Comment: it's ejs template i'm using always

Comment: Where is the placeholder for the message you are trying to show?

Comment: message created on the passport js and it's showing below the ejs template i provideded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is going on. But lets try something.

I believe, your flash message its been erased.

Look:

Here is your code:

```
app.post('/sign-up', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/sign-up',
        failureFlash : true // you are passing this parameter
    }));
```

Look at the passport code:

```
...
if (options.failureFlash) {
        var flash = options.failureFlash; // flash here is 'true'
        if (typeof flash == 'string') { // not 'string'
          flash = { type: 'error', message: flash };
        }
        flash.type = flash.type || 'error'; // 'flash.type' is undefined, 'flash' is 'true', so not is gonna happen

        var type = flash.type || challenge.type || 'error'; // 'type' now is 'error'
        msg = flash.message || challenge.message || challenge;
        if (typeof msg == 'string') {
          req.flash(type, msg); // value assigned: ['error', 'yourmessage']
        }
      }
...
```

So, I believe, if your call:

```
app.get('/sign-up', function(req, res){
        res.render('signup', { message: req.flash('error') }); // changing 'signupMessage' to error, it would works.
    });
```

Or, you can change the `failureFlash`  parameter to and object:

```
app.post('/sign-up', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile',
            failureRedirect : '/sign-up',
            failureFlash : { type: 'signupMessage' }
        }));
```

and keep this intact:

```
res.render('signup', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
```

Let me know if it works.

Cheers!

Comment: bro did you clearly understand what exactly need to do. if you see the passport js i'm trying to check every req.body.email, req.body.first, req.body.last. if these 3 fields empty the flash message display as i set it.but when i'm checking the username and password field the page redirected but doesn't show me the error. but other 3 fields can see the flash message.

Comment: the code worked perfectly. thank you for wasting your time to help me. So now i need to know where is the place to change the error "missing credentials".. i need to modify it as my own custom error please if you don't mind let me know where is it

Comment: the first way is working fine but the second way is not working. and also i cannot display the username and email exists errors. please let me know a way to display both of these errors

Comment: About the second way, it works. I believe you're doing something wrong. About the others question. I think will be easier if your open another thread.

Comment: do you mean should i need to post another question ??. and can you please give me a reputation for this questionn

Comment: ok bro i;ll post another question. so don't forget to give a reputation for this question. and thankx for your help. i already gave a reputation for your answer